# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'upper' when fetching Reddit darkmode

Tags: python, attributes, nonetype

Im trying to fetch Reddit's dark mode but resulting in this error in the title, here's my current code;

```
if getenv("THEME").upper() == "DARK":
            cookie_file = open('./video_creation/data/cookie.json')
            cookies = json.load(cookie_file)
            context.add_cookies(cookies)
```

Comment: your `getenv("THEME")` method returns a None value, check if it works correctly and returns a string!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getenv()` function is returning a None value, probably because of not being able to find the variable or something likewise. You can also try to use a try-except block to resolve to an answer incase of a TypeError. Also, if this is the `getenv` from the `os` module then you can provide a default value as mentioned above.

The try block could be done as:

```py
try:
    if getenv("THEME").upper() == "DARK":
            cookie_file = open('./video_creation/data/cookie.json')
            cookies = json.load(cookie_file)
            context.add_cookies(cookies)
except TypeError:
    # Do something if variable is not found or something like that
    smth_default()
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, the return value of `getenv("THEME")` is clearly `None`, upon which you cannot call `upper`. You should investigate why `getenv("THEME")` is not returning the result you expect.

If this is `os.getenv` you can also provide a default value.

```
getenv("THEME", default='light').upper()
```